# Any way to enable timed administrator lockout from local machine in Windows Server 2008R2?

Tags: windows-7

The account lockout functionality in the Local Security Policy doesn't apply to administrators by default, apparently.

However, it seems admin lockout can be enabled [by modifying the domain PasswordProperties attribute](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2017/07/11/built-in-administrator-account-lockout/).  But, I don't have a group policy set and it isn't clear to me if doing so will allow me to do what I want as it seems it might simply lock out failed network access attempts.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: There a reason you cannot set the policy?  You don't have to be connected to a AD domain, a single machine can be configured, through the use of group policies.

Comment: Ok, I think I managed to set up a group policy with the desired object.  Now I just need to find the Pwd-Properties attribute, but so far it eludes me.  Currently searching in the Active Directory Admin Center, but not seeing anything.  Any hints?

Comment: Why would you want to allow the `administrator` account to be locked out? That is the only account that can't be locked out - for obvious reasons. Why not tell us the purpose, then we can tell you the correct way to accomplish your goal.  You should either disable the `administrator` account and work with alternative user accounts, or restrict `administrator` access to local console logons only. There is no best practice that suggests locking out the `administrator` account with failed logons.

Comment: Productivity reasons.  I want to limit access to the admin account for specified periods of time.  I'll have a locked down guest account to do work on.